# Partial thread lock: mix of thread-safe and unsafe code

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have two methods, say, `read()` and `init()`.

`read` is re-entrant and thread-safe; it can (and should) be executed in parallel by multiple threads.

However, any other mix of them is not thread-safe; e.g. `read` must block if `init` is being executed and vice versa, not to mention `init` on itself. (Things are complicated because it's all a wrapper to unmanaged code).

How do I organise locks in this situation (in .net, C# or VB)?

`init` on itself seems trivial: I can wrap it in the standard `lock ()` / `SyncLock` mechanism. But is there are a similar simple mechanism that allows `read` to:

1. Block on the same lock object used for `init` but not acquire exclusivity on it (otherwise `read` will block itself on it).
2. When block is released, flag another object (a mutex?) on which `init` should block in addition to its own lock (but here in `read` we don't check it).
3. Run the code.
4. Release the second object.

As often happens in multi-threading, there must be many pitfalls I'm not very familiar with. For example, I see the read-lock object may be flagged multiple times by multiple reads running in parallel, and must fully unwind before `init` can go. It all feels like a fairly common situation and there must be standard ways of dealing with it...

Comment: That's just a long-winded way of saying "read() is not thread-safe".  If you cannot make sure that read is never called until after init was called then you really *do* need to interlock.

Comment: Well, not entirely, but it _is_ safe for concurrent reads. It does seem to be the perfect design case for `ReaderWriterLockSlim` mentioned below. As for 'no read before init', this is just plain logics, not thread interlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ReaderWriterLock or ReaderWriterLockSlim (preferred in new code) classes would seem to be what you want here, your init() method being the writer.

> ReaderWriterLock is used to synchronize access to a resource. At any
>   given time, it allows either concurrent read access for multiple
>   threads, or write access for a single thread. In a situation where a
>   resource is changed infrequently, a ReaderWriterLock provides better
>   throughput than a simple one-at-a-time lock, such as Monitor.
>
> ReaderWriterLock works best where most accesses are reads, while
>   writes are infrequent and of short duration. Multiple readers
>   alternate with single writers, so that neither readers nor writers are
>   blocked for long periods.

It's been part of the .NET framework since version 1.1 and is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Never came across this one, but it does seem to be exactly what I need.
One thing I had to work around was that `ReaderWriterLockSlim` favours writes over reads when there is a waiting queue, while I want the opposite. But this can be simulated by using `TryEnterWriteLock()` with a very short timeout.

Comment: NB: You can get the source code for the ReaderWriterLockSlim on the Microsoft web site at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/